# TensorFlow max_pool2d wrong output size

Tags: tensorflow, max-pooling

I'm trying to use a max pool layer with filter size 2x2, so I expect the output size to be roughly half the input size.
The input size is 9x14x64, but for some reason the output size is 7x12x64 (see the attached [TensorBoard graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UyZ8.png)).

Here is the TensorFlow code:

```
layer = conv2d(layer, 64, 3, 2, activation_fn=None, scope="conv_2", name=name)
layer = max_pool2d(layer, 2, 1, scope="max_1", name=name)
layer = conv2d(layer, 32, 3, 1, activation_fn=None, scope="conv_3", name=name)
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are tensorflow default data_format `NHWC`; but your input format is `NCHW`. So you need to change your input format to `NHWC`

```
N -batch_size, H-height, W-width, C-num_channels
```

Note: Max-pool only changes `height` and `width` of the input feature maps. There will be no effect on `num_channels` (it will be same for both input and output).

If you want to change the number of channels then you can use a `1x1` convolution layer as follows.

```
# 9 x 14 x 64
layer = max_pool2d(layer, 2, 2, scope="max_1", name=name, padding='SAME')
# output size 5x7x64
# to reduce num_channels use 1x1 conv
layer = conv2d(layer, 32, 1, 1, activation_fn=None, scope="conv_pool", name=name, padding='SAME')
# output size 5x7x32
```

Comment: then the output is expected. `max_pool` only change the `height` and `width`, not `num_channels`

Comment: It actually changed height and width. Take a look on the tensorboard graph screenshot.

Comment: see my above comment.

Comment: The number of channels is not changed. There are 64 channels in the input and output. The only dimensions changed are H and W.